Where is the original procedure of sandhyavandana mentioned?
Although we get sandhyavandana method by shakhas etc..How did Brahmanas do sandhyavandana in Vedic age? They had no shakhas as they learnt the entire veda.Is it found in sama veda? Kindly point thanks
